# python delete row where most columns are nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I'm importing data where from excel where some rows may have notes in a column and are not truly part of the dataframe. dummy Eg. below:

```
H1            H2           H3
*highlighted cols are PII
sam          red           5
pam          blue          3
rod          green         11
 * this is the end of the data
```

When the above file is imported into dfPA it looks like:

```
dfPA:
Index     H1            H2           H3
1         *highlighted cols are PII
2         sam          red           5
3         pam          blue          3
4         rod          green         11
5         * this is the end of the data
```

I want to delete the first and last row. This is what I've done.

```
#get count of cols in df
input: cntcols = dfPA.shape[1]
output: 3

#get count of cols with nan in df
input: a = dfPA.shape[1] - dfPA.count(axis=1)
output: 
0     2
1     3
2     3
4     3
5     2
(where a is a series)

#convert a from series to df
dfa = a.to_frame()

#delete rows where no. of nan's are greater than 'n'
n = 1
for r, row in dfa.iterrows():
    if (cntcols - dfa.iloc[r][0]) > n:
        i = row.name
        dfPA = dfPA.drop(index=i)
```

This doesn't work. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method. It has a `thresh` parameter that you can use to define a minimum number of NaN to drop the row/column.

Imagine the following dataframe:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,1,np.nan], [1,1,1,1], [1,np.nan,1,1], [np.nan,1,1,1]], columns=list('ABCD'))

     A    B  C    D
0  1.0  NaN  1  NaN
1  1.0  1.0  1  1.0
2  1.0  NaN  1  1.0
3  NaN  1.0  1  1.0
```

You can drop columns with NaN using:

```
>>> df.dropna(axis=1)

   C
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  1
```

The `thresh` parameter defines the minimum number of non-NaN values to keep the column:

```
>>> df.dropna(thresh=3, axis=1)

     A  C    D
0  1.0  1  NaN
1  1.0  1  1.0
2  1.0  1  1.0
3  NaN  1  1.0
```

If you want to reason in terms of the number of NaN:

```
# example for a minimum of 2 NaN to drop the column
>>> df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns)-(2-1), axis=1)
```

If the rows rather than the columns need to be filtered, remove the axis parameter or use `axis=0`:

```
>>> df.dropna(thresh=3)
```

Comment: thanks this worked. I'd seen thresh around when I was researching. Didn't realise this is what it did.  Accepting your answer, but incase you want your answer to be accurate, I want to delete rows not columns so revised the axis value in your solution ```dfPA = dfPA.dropna(thresh=1, axis=0)```.

Comment: How to delete the row with the largest number of nans?

Comment: @dawid it depends on the exact logic, what if you have several of those rows? You should maybe ask a new question?